# Binding to a user-defined list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `MultipleImageEntryHost` (a self-defined child of `WindowsFormHost`), which contains a list (specifically an `ObservableCollection`) of `FileInfo`s. I want to bind this list - that is, make sure that the source of the data (a `MultipleImageEntry`'s list of `FileInfo`s) will update the list. While obviously I want the public to  have access to this list (the binding needs it), I don't want them to be able to switch the list object themselves. How do I do this?

Comment: Public getter, private setter. Any problems with that approach?

Comment: I get the following error: `'Images' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.`

Comment: Did you try setting the mode to "OneWay"?

Comment: Still get the same error.